# ORACLE Permission on tables from indirect database link

Tags: oracle

I have a table "`TABLE_A`" that is in `DB A`, and I got a schema "`SCH_B`" in `DB B`. Now a database link is created in "`SCH_B`" that connect to `DB A`, and the "`TABLE_A`" is also granted `SELECT permission` to "`SCH_B`".

Now I would like to create another schema "`SCH_C`" in `DB B`, but database link is not created for "`SCH_C`", is it possible for "`SCH_C`" to have `SELECT permission` to "`TABLE_A`"?

Answer (score 0):

A database link connects to the remote database as a user in that remote database.  If we assume that the database link in question connects to database B as the user `SCH_B` then you would be able to access whatever tables in B the user `SCH_B` has access to over the database link.  If `SCH_B` is granted access to objects in `SCH_C` then you would be able to access those objects via the database link.  Of course, you would have to qualify the name unless you also create synonyms in B, i.e.

```
SELECT *
  FROM sch_c.table_name@database_link
```